# C# - How to handle model's property change to invoke notify in ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, binding

Following MVVM architecture, we have a view with 2 `DataGrids` whose data are related and view-model having `ObservableCollection<Model>`.

Model have boolean property, based on which is one of the grid enabled/disabled. Everything works well and when I change the selected `Model`, the grid becames unusable. However, when I change the property, the `Notify` of the customer property `IsSelectedModelChecked` is not invoked (When I check/uncheck the checkbox in 1st grid, I need to invoke `Notify` over the property `IsSelectedModelChecked`).

**Q: How am I able to invoke property change on Model's property change?**

I've checked several questions, but none of them answered mine. I'd like to provide some ideas from top of my head, but I don't have a clue. Thanks

---

*<unnecessary code ommited>*

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid
      ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModel}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"
                 Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Check"
                 Binding="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<DataGrid
      IsEnabled="{Binding IsSelectedModelChecked}"/>
```

**Model:**

```
public class Model : Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ObservableObject
{
    private string mName = @"<Name>";
    public string Name
    {
        get { return mName; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mName, value); }
    }

    private bool mIsChecked = false;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return mIsChecked; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mIsChecked, value); }
    }
}
```

**View-Model:**

```
public class ViewModel : Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ObservableObject
{
    private Model mSelectedModel;
    public Model SelectedModel
    {
        get { return mSelectedModel; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref mSelectedModel, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelectedModelChecked));
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Model> mModels = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Models
    {
        get { return mModels; }
        set { SetProperty(ref mModels, value); }
    }

    public bool IsSelectedModelChecked => SelectedModel?.IsChecked ?? false;
}
```

Comment: Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.ObservableObject? Take that garbage and throw it in the gotdamn trash basket. It requires you call SetProperty and send in *the name of the property being set*. Without this, it doesn't notify anybody about a property changing (see Name and IsChecked in your model's code). No wonder it's not working as expected. Just find an implementation of INPC that uses the CallerMemberNameAttribute to get the name of the property being updated.

Comment: @Will that thing is working.. You have not understand the question at all. Notifying of property change (in model) is not propagated to related property (in view-model), because the relation is not "clarified" anywhere. Otherwise the bindings from view etc works as expected.. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extension to [Haukinger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49239052/7167572)'s answer. He mentions issue with memory leak, that can occur when the ViewModel instance will be destroyed, but the model will exist and the handler will be still attached to the events.

In such case, WPF has implemented something called [Weak Event Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/weak-event-patterns), which allows to handle such situation. For the property change, there is existing [PropertyChangedEventManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventmanager) that implements such Weak Event Pattern. The code should be written as:

```
public Model SelectedModel
{
    get { return mSelectedModel; }
    set
    {
        if (mSelectedModel != null)
            PropertyChangedEventManager.RemoveHandler(mSelectedModel, OnSelectedModelPropertyChanged, "");

        SetProperty(ref mSelectedModel, value);

        if (mSelectedModel != null)
            PropertyChangedEventManager.AddHandler(mSelectedModel, OnSelectedModelPropertyChanged, "");

        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelectedModelChecked));
    }
}

private void OnSelectedModelPropertyChanged( object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.PropertyName == nameof(Model.IsChecked))
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelectedModelChecked));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to listen for your `SelectedModel`'s `PropertyChanged` event.

I.e.

```
public Model SelectedModel
{
    get { return mSelectedModel; }
    set
    {
        if (mSelectedModel != null)
            mSelectedModel.PropertyChanged -= OnSelectedModelPropertyChanged;
        SetProperty(ref mSelectedModel, value);
        if (mSelectedModel != null)
            mSelectedModel.PropertyChanged += OnSelectedModelPropertyChanged;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelectedModelChecked));
    }
}

private void OnSelectedModelPropertyChanged( object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args )
{
    if (args.PropertyName == nameof(Model.IsChecked))
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelectedModelChecked));
}
```

Also, you will want to take care about leaking the view model instance if your model instance lives longer than the view model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You set me on the right track and I've attached my own answer, as it also includes the handling for the possible memory leak.